# Can not find the link to full Android samples in android developer

Tags: android, sample

I can not find the android samples which must be in GitHub by the information i read in android developer. I finnished with Fragments section for example and now i want to see all the full samples. Please someone give me a link.

Comment: Do you use android studio ?

Comment: yep, i am using Android Studio

Comment: are you talking about this repository? https://github.com/googlesamples?utf8=✓&query=android

Answer (score 2):

You can also import samples directly using Android Studio.

[image: studio]

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a sample in here and just press download
http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

[image]

EDIT:
And here is a link to the google samples github https://github.com/googlesamples

Answer (score 0):

You can find the samples here in the main window of android studio. To get to main window close every open project in your studio and you would get this [main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifnjy.png) screen. Go to last link and you would get list of all samples with their [official google samples](https://github.com/googlesamples) repo link. You can then download them as zip or clone using git bash.I haven't seen [this](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples) link but you can check  if you want. If you go to the last folder [link](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/training) you would find all developer training examples. Hope this helps :)

**Note**:*I don't know why but there is no main windows screen in beta and canary build versions of android studio. So please use latest stable android studio version located [here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/stable).*